# Change the name of the route in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, router

For example http://magento2.loc/checkout changed to http://magento2.loc/supercheckout

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Modify frontName tag in below direction

> [VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/frontend/routes.xml

if you want change frontend route of extension

> [VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

if you want change backend route of extension

More example you can see in nice clear module:  vendor/magento/module-cms

Comment: I changed the name in the core - it works . But I need to change the names in my module.

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you..........http://inchoo.net/magento-2/routing-in-magento-2/

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/routing-in-magento-2/

Comment: I read it . It says how to create a router , but does not say how to change its name without affecting the core.

Answer (score -1):

Go to vendor\magento\module-checkout\etc\frontend\routes.xml
Change the following code

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="checkout" frontName="checkout">
            <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

TO

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="checkout" frontName="supercheckout">
            <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Please note if you are making changes for id attribute of route to "supercheckout", You need to change all the layout files in vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout folder with the starting name as "checkout" to "supercheckout" e.g. files will be checkout_cart_configure.xml to supercheckout_cart_configure.xml and so on.

Comment: Changing a core module like this is never a good idea, it is an especially bad idea when the core is in vendor as this is managed by composer and could be changed with a minor version update.